# Serilog writes errors to file but does not write information

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have ASP Core 6.0 app
I use Serilog for logging
I try to write in files. And I want to divide info which i write in logs
I want to write Information level in one file , error level in second file

Here is my settings file

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs/log_.txt",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": {
            "type": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "pathFormat": "Logs/ERR-.txt",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "formatter": {
            "type": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": 
    [ 
      "FromLogContext"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "ClassEdu.Lti.AdobeConnect.Host"
    }
  }
}
```

These packages were added by me

```
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="7.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
```

Code to add serilog

```
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.logging.json");
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
    loggerConfiguration
        .ReadFrom
        .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
```

As a result, only errors are written to the file, but not Information level.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: RollingFile has been superseded by File. I believe you might need to do a `.MinimumLevel.Information` somewhere in the config; validate that by wiring it without the json config and then doing the json bit after you make it work.